# Upload Image from Android to GAE datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to upload image from Android Client to GAE (Google App Engine) datastore ?

no tutorials found yet, have tried for last 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, i am able to upload image like this

1. Create POJO Photo

public class photo {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;



public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private Blob blobImage;

public Blob getBlobImage() {
    return blobImage;
}

public void setBlobImage(byte[] bytes) {
    this.blobImage = new Blob(bytes);
}

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private String type;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

1. Generate Cloud Endpoint (right clicking -> google -> generate cloud endpoint)
2. Genereate CLient Side Libraries (right click project -> google -> generate client libraries)
3. In your android application -> open photoendpoint.model (package) -> Photo.java 
   replace your 
   **public byte[] decodeBlobImage() {
   }**
   to 
   this

   **public byte[] decodeBlobImage() {
   return com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(blobImage);
   }**
4. perform this in your activity

   ```
                   Photo photo = new Photo();
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
       R.drawable.sherlock);
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
       byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
       photo.encodeBlobImage(byteArray);
       photo.setName("Sherlock");
       photo.setName("sherlock");
       photo.setType("image/jpeg");
       photo.setId((long) 8232);
       Photoendpoint.Builder builder = new Photoendpoint.Builder(
       AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
               null);
       builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

       Photoendpoint endpoint = builder.build();

       Log.d("Exception", "inserting image");
       try {
           Log.d("Exception", "inserting");
           endpoint.insertphoto(photo).execute();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.d("Exception", "" + e);
       }
   ```

Comment: Also the method to encode and decode are missing in the POJO.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to decide how large your image file that you are uploading is going to be. This is because if you are using a Datastore that at best you could use a TEXT field that could save only upto 1 MB of data.

I suggest that you look at using the Blobstore or better still the Google Cloud Storage service as a way to save your Image Data.

The steps will be roughly as follows:

- Do a POST from your Android code with the Image bytes.
- On the App Engine side, receive the bytes, encode them and then use the Google Cloud Storage Service to save the data. You could then use the GCS Identifier and save that in the Datastore as a reference to the image.

Take a look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168930/store-image-to-blobstore-from-android-client-and-retrieve-blobkey-and-upload-url?rq=1) for sample code.

Comment: Please reply to answer below :)

Comment: @Romin do you recommend the method used in the accepted answer?