# Get BlobKey type from JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

We're trying to build application which will store images to blobstore.

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168930/store-image-to-blobstore-from-android-client-and-retrieve-blobkey-and-upload-url/22189239#22189239) and added it to endpoint project.
Now the /uploaded servlet returns to client JSONObject like this:

```
    json.put("servingUrl", servingUrl);
    json.put("blobKey", blobKey);
```

There is a PictureEntity class. Where the field blobKey is of the type BlobKey and I can send another HttpPost request with all needed data to server, get the needed String from html entity and apply 
`picture.setBlobKey(blobKey);` on server side.

But since I use EndPoints I don't want to transfer all the data again to another servlet on the server. I want to use endpoints. And it seems that they should somehow support BlobKey type.
At least GAE creates model for them but when I try to do the same on client side I always get an error:

> The method setBlobKey(BlobKey) in the type PictureEntity is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: not really an expert in google cloud, but from what you posted seems like you have to pass a `BlobKey` object to your `setBlobKey` method instead of `String`. And to get this object (or a list of `BlobKey`s) I imagine you need to look for specific API, no ?

Comment: Agreed. But the problem is I get a JSON object which contains BlobKey in format `"blobKey":"\u003cBlobKey: pVYVYrL5XWhnJyvTA1iiAA\u003e","servingUrl":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/img/pVYVYrL5XWhnJyvTA1iiAA"` But I can't get the BlobKey type from the String. There should be some way to transfer BlobKey object in JSON or transform string to BlobKey in client app.