# Retrieving blob key from blobstore with HTTP method

Tags: java, android, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have been referring to this post [Store image to Blobstore from android client and retrieve blobkey and upload url to store in Datastore. - GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168930/store-image-to-blobstore-from-android-client-and-retrieve-blobkey-and-upload-url) . The last two code blocks below are probably the most relevant as they are the code that sends and receives the blob key between app engine and my android app.

The blob is uploading just fine. **When I have my servlet return the blob key I continue to get this in my logs:**

```
405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

Here is my BlobUrlGet.java on app engine that provides a URL for the upload of the blob:

```
public class BlobUrlGet extends HttpServlet {


BlobstoreService blServ =    BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {


    UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("abc123-974.appspot.com");
    String blobUploadUrl = blServ.createUploadUrl("/Uploaded", uploadOptions);




    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.print(blobUploadUrl);
}

}
```

I then use this code in my android app to upload the file and then listen for the blob key:

```
private class GetBlobUrlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    HttpResponse response = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){  
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://abc123-974.appspot.com/bloburlget"); 


        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


HttpEntity urlEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream in = null;
        in = urlEntity.getContent();


}
String str = ""; 
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
String encoding = "UTF-8";


    IOUtils.copy(in, writer, encoding);

str = writer.toString();



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(str);

File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/ContactDetail.json");
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f2);


MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    response = httpClient.execute(httppost);




String str2 = "";

str2 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

//Getting that Post is not supported method when I print the following string:
blobKeyString = str2;
```

**Lastly my Uploaded.java that is supposed to return the blob key but it isn't:**

```
public class Uploaded extends HttpServlet {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
        .getBlobstoreService();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

            List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("file");

            BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get(0);

            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

           String blobKeyString = blobKey.getKeyString();

            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.print(blobKeyString);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
```

Why does my String blobKeyString continue to have the value of an html document with this in the body when it makes it back to the android app:

```
405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

Comment: so if you remove the print of the offensive line, you don't get the "method POST" error? To me, looking into the error, I'd say your URL that receives the blob just needs a "doPost" method

Comment: @Patrice . Thanks for pointing that out. I changed my doGet to doPost and now it works great. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks! If you write that up in an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Very welcome! Always happy to help users on the platform :) posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error, it means that you need a way to handle a POST request to your app.

I would change the servlet on the URL receiving the request to have a "doPost" instead of a "doGet".